# Weird Illustrator 2019 Node and Shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

[image]
So, I have a weird illustrator problem, As shown in the picture above, the control line at blue arrow [B] is not lining up with the actual object despite the control line at the yellow arrow [A] is in line with the actual object. They're both the same object.

What I do to make this object :

1. I use pen tool to create the stroke
2. I outline the strokes
3. The green arrow [C] originally a sharp corner and I intended to round it off, but it's too narrow so the option not available, what I ended up doing is, making a half a circle and merge it with pathfinder at that corner [C].
4. When I tried to smooth it all out, I notice that the line at blue arrow [B] is not lining up, as if I use roughen effect despite the section at yellow arrow [A] is perfectly aligned.

I'm so confused.

What I already tried :

1. Restarting Illustrator.
2. Make new documents.
3. Make new object but using the same stroke object.
4. Modifying the stroke object to be smoother but after I outline it, the problem persist although not as noticeable.

I've been using Illustrator for more than a decade now and this is the first time I encountered this weird problem.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Turn off Align to Pixel Grid maybe?

Comment: I already turned it off. No snapping of any kind, even smart guides is turned off.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Check the Appearance panel. Are there any effects added?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Hmm, not that I can see. It's really weird.